# How to use vim regex to turn a string into a symbol in a Rails schema file?

Tags: regex, vim

So I have the following in a rails schema.rb file:

```
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "size"
t.integer  "id"
```

If I wanted to turn it into:

```
t.integer  :user_id
t.string   :size
t.integer  :id
```

What is the substitution I use?  I've tried `%s/\"\(\w+\)\"/:\1/g` and get a *Pattern not found* error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `+`

```
:%s/\"\(\w\+\)\"/:\1/g
```

Or you can use a negated character class, `[^"]`, instead of `\w`:

```
:%s/\"\([^"]*\)\"/:\1/g
```

For more help see:

```
:h /\+
:h magic
```